# Get current time based on Timezone even if user changed his device time

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to create a timer which compares a date sent from a server and the user's device date.

Problem is when the user changes his device time, it affects my timer.

Is there a way to get the device's timezone date so i can use it instead.

Comment: No, You can't with js

Comment: You shouldn't be storing local time on your server.

Comment: The browser gets its time from the device, so if the device's time is changed the browser doesn't know any different.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [getTimezoneOffset() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) off a newly created Date however that won't be invariant from the user changing their time/locale, your best option would be to geolocate them and fetch the current time from elsewhere (your server).